# Adding multiple attributes in XML node

Tags: xml, t-sql, insert, sql-server-2012

I want to add two new attributes for all nodes. The attributes name and values are the same for all elements.

I have the following XML structure:

```
<question id="1001"></question>
<question id="1002"></question>
<question id="1003"></question>
<question id="1004"></question>
```

and want to transform it as follows:

```
<question id="1001" test1="1" test2="2"></question>
<question id="1002" test1="1" test2="2"></question>
<question id="1003" test1="1" test2="2"></question>
<question id="1004" test1="1" test2="2"></question>
```

I was not able to find an example in the documentation of how multiple attributes are added,so I started with adding only the first one:

```
SELECT T.c.modify('insert attribute test1 {"1"} into (/question)[1]')
FROM @SetQuestionsAndAnswersDetailsXML.nodes('/question') T(c)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Msg 8137, Level 16, State 1, Line 89
Incorrect use of the XML data type method 'modify'. A non-mutator method is expected in this context.
```

Has anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately,

> The modify() method of the xml data type can only be used in the SET
>   clause of an UPDATE statement.

So, I need to create a table variable, to insert the records there and then to modify the xmls.

In order to add multiple attributes in one *modify insert* statement you can use the syntax below:

```
UPDATE @TempTable
SET XMLColumn.modify('insert (attribute test1 {"1" },attribute test2 {"2"}) into (/question)[1]')
```